# How to calculate average of percentage for each row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

[image]

In column D, for each student I'd like to find average of percentage of all the tests they took.

For Student 1, I need to take percentage of each test by 8/10, 25/25, 35/50 and find average in D6, etc.

I tried `=average(($E6:$E100)/($E3:$AB3))` but it did not work. How can I get this?

Comment: so you want average per row of columns E:AB?

Comment: You have referred to "Column D". Would you please be more specific - are you referring to Cell D5 - "the class average", or an average for each student - that is, a value in each cell in Column D, or both, or something else. In any event, disregarding the syntax of a Google formula, would you please advise the values that you expect from a successful outcome.

Comment: Updated. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(E6:Z), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(B6:B), 
 "avg(Col"&ROW(B6:B)-ROW(B6)+1&")", )))&""),
 "select Col2")*1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I got the same result with `average(E7:G7)`, etc. It's beyond me, but presumably you could turn that into an array formula, and it would copy down automatically. My only concern is, what does it actually mean?

Comment: It did not work for me. I need to find the percentage first. For st2, by 7/10, 20/25, 40/50 and finding the average.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the class average, to appear in cell D5
`=(sum(E7:G))/count(D7:D)`

Based on the test data, the class average is 67.75.

Answer (score 0):

I think just for 10/10, 25/25, 35/50  you can try with:

```
=Average(Arrayformula({e6:g6}/{e3:g3}))
```